# MySQL And JDBC Related

Tags: mysql, jdbc

We are using MySQL Database and using jdbc we select a no from a table and then increment manually by one. 
After that insert into this table. In which we are getting following error:-> 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry

Comment: Please show some code. The error is pretty straightforward, so you probably are doing sth wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

for sure you are inserting a duplicate of the primary key in your table.

write here your insert statement so we can help you much more.